# Updating Views Module Not Working 7.x-3.13 --> 7.x-3.15

Tags: views

Drupal has been telling me to update my views module from 7.x-3.13 to 7.x-3.15.

Everything seems to work fine. However, when I return to the admin pages, I receive "No update information available. Run cron or check manually." I proceed to run cron and Drupal simply tells me that I need to update the module again.

I've manually updated to the newest version (7.x-3.15) and even to the dev version (7.x-3.x-dev). In both cases, Drupal continued to tell me I needed to update the module.

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Did you run **update.php**? `http://yourwebsite.com/update.php`

Answer (score 0):

I checked Views module versions from 7.x-3.13 to 7.x-3.15 and it seems that there are no changes needed to be applied to the database (the views.install file didn't change between the two versions). I think you need just to override the module directory with the new version and clear all caches.

Comment: This is what I was thinking too. But even after clearing my cache, Drupal insists that I need to update the module.

Comment: It seems your drupal setup is still pointing to old view folder. Just try to remove the old folder if you saved in modules directory. And go to /admin/modules path it will rebuild the modules path. And clear cache.
Hope this will help.